# Multiple UICollectionView PerformBatchUpdate

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview

I'm doing some animations in `UICollectionView` with custom layout and flow.

When I want to animate my `UICollectionView`s I'm doing this:

```
    [localCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
         [localCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         [localLabelCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{ //problem here
              [localLabelCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];

          } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
              hatching = NO;
          }];

     }];
```

1. Animate my first collection view using batchperforming
2. On finish, animate my second collection view

The problem is the second perform is really slow (like 5 seconds or more before animations) when first is immediate, like its completion call.

I tried even to do them separately like this:

```
    [localCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
         [localCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     }];

    [localLabelCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{ //problem here
              [localLabelCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];

          } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
              hatching = NO;
          }];
```

Same problem appear. Any suggestions or explanations are welcomed.

P.S.:

First solution, for me, have to work because of using only main UI thread for animation. That's why I think second example (without dealing with worst UI animations) couldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it like this and works like a charms:

```
[localCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
     [localCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
     [localLabelCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    hatching = NO;
}];
```

Seems like performBatch update enqueue itself (even on different object) on multiple call.